# How to get nearest id when i pass a number

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table

```
id
---
10
20
30
40
```

I want to get output 20 if i pass numbers between 11-19 30 if I pass numbers between 21-29

How do I do that ?

Answer (score 11):

please, try this one

```
select min(id) from your_table where id >= your_number_value
```

hope this help :)

Answer (score 1):

Select where id is larger than your input, select top 1 and then order by id ascending

So

```
SELECT TOP 1 Id
FROM <YOUR TABlE>
WHERE ID >= <INPUT>
ORDER BY ID ASC 
--specifying asc is essentially irrelevant as it's default, but it's nice to show intent.
```

This should give you 20 if your input is between 11 and 19

Answer (score -1):

Lets say the number to be passed is in a variable 'var_num'.

Try similar to this -

```
SELECT id
FROM table_name
WHERE id = CASE 
     WHEN (var_num % 10) > 0
         THEN (var_num - (var_num % 10)) + 10
     ELSE
         var_num
     END;
```

This will return 20 if 11-19 is passed, and 20 if 20 itself is passed.

Comment: This is a very complicated way to get the answer, while there are much simpler solutions,  And it will not work if var_num is 5. also, it assumes that the id value is always going to be a multiplication of 10, that's usually not the case in id columns.